# TypeScript type casting issue - example

Tags: typescript, interface, casting

I am faced with a "type casting interface"-issue in TypeScript. I dont understand why my interface is not interfering! Please see my example below:

```
interface IProduct {
    age  : number;
    price : number;
}

class Product{
    public age: number = 22;
}

let products : Array<Product> = [new Product(), new Product()];
let products_stringify = JSON.stringify(products);
let products_parsed = JSON.parse(products_stringify);

**// Now my problem starts here....**

// Why interface IProduct does not interfere ?
let firstProduct1: IProduct = products_parsed[0];
console.dir(typeof products_parsed[0]);// -> object

// When i do a typecasting with <object> the interface interferes, and throws an error!
let firstProduct2 : IProduct = <object>products_parsed[0];
console.dir(typeof products_parsed[0]);// -> object
```

Comment: You are strigifying the products and read them again. That makes them lose any type information.

Comment: also Product doesn't correctly implement the IProduct interface, it's missing the price property.

Comment: The missing of the price property is intended. If I check the type of the first product object (after parsing), its a "object" type for both cases... in the first example the interface IProduct had to interfere... but it did not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stringifying the products array and parsing it again makes it lose any type information you had before. That's why it is not read back as you'd expect.

The return type of JSON.parse is **any**.

Also an object of type **object** can't be assign can't be assigned to IProduct since it's missing the 2 properties defined on that interface. **object** is an empty objecct {}.

Comment: Ok, it seems that in TypeScript interfaces do not interefere, when the type is of <any>! Thanx a lot!